# How to copy a row from a table to another table which have more columns than the first one in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-insert

Please read my problem carefully because i am very bad at explaining it and please help me out of this problem .

Let suppose I made 2 tables named `table1`, which has only 2 columns, and second table named `table2` which has 3 columns but in the 3 columns , 2 columns are same as the 2 columns of `table1`.

So I want to copy a row from the 2 columns of `table1` to the same type of 2 columns of `table2` and keeping 3rd column as null in mysql.

So please tell how to do it .

Answer (score 3):

Consider the [`insert ... select` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html):

```
insert into table2(col1, col2)
select col1, col2 from table1
```